# Execute SQL Query build up from values in a table (Tablename and whereclause)

Tags: t-sql

I have a table basically like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CCC_Action_Recalc](
    -- ...
    [CCC_Tablename] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [CCC_WhereClause] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    -- ...
)
```

Now, what i want to do is executing an SQL Query like this:

```sql
select *
from CCC_Action_Recalc ar
where
--- 1
0 < 
( 
   select count(*)
   from ar.CCC_TableName
   where
   ar.CCC_WhereClause
)
--- 2
```

This query shall only deliver result when the where Clause between 1 and 2 delivers results.

But it throws an error like:
"An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'."

There must be a way to tell tsql to handle table values (tables and whereclauses) as part of a new query. Is that possible?

Comment: What you are talking about is dynamic SQL. You need to generate sql query you want as string and then execute it.